# Getter and Setter in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In my MainActivity I have a Switch and a Button, After changing the switch status, Once the button is clicked I want to get the switch status true/false. To do this, I've implemented Getter and Setter, for unknown reason, once I set the value, i'm always getting false.

**MainActivity**

```
 Switch profession = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.profswitch);
profession.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        GetSwitch SP = new GetSwitch();
        SP.setSetClicked(isChecked);
    }
});

Button profButton = findViewById(R.id.btnSwitchNxt);
profButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       GetSwitch sw = new GetSwitch();
       boolean setClicked = sw.isSetClicked();
       Log.i("GetSwitch",setClicked+"");

   }
});
```

**GetSwitch**

```
public class GetSwitch{

    private boolean setClicked;

    public void setSetClicked(boolean setClicked) {
        this.setClicked = setClicked;
        Log.i("SetSwitch",this.setClicked+"");
    }

    public boolean isSetClicked() {
        return setClicked;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: You're creating a new `GetSwitch` instance every time the `Switch` changes, or the `Button`'s clicked. You'd need to create one single `GetSwitch` instance that you use in both places. However, have you considered just doing `boolean setClicked = profession.isChecked();` in the `OnClickListener`? No need for a separate class.

Comment: I have not thought about it. thank you!. it worked like a charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using two separate instances of the same class for getting same property. When you are updating a property of an instance that change belongs to that instance. You can do something like this:

```
Switch profession = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.profswitch);
GetSwitch sw = new GetSwitch();
profession.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        sw.setSetClicked(isChecked);
    }
});

Button profButton = findViewById(R.id.btnSwitchNxt);
profButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       boolean setClicked = sw.isSetClicked();
       Log.i("GetSwitch",setClicked+"");
   }
});
```

See here I am getting and setting the property of same instance so that they are not changed. You can also define this instance in the constructor of the class and reference them using `this.sw` as a good practice.

Comment: Thank you for this, i was completely unaware of it. However @Mike said i have changed it as follows `boolean setClicked = profession.isChecked();` which was much more efficient without a separate class

Answer (score 0):

You are using different object for setting and getting value. You just need to declare one GetSwitch object, which has to be like below..

```
   GetSwitch SP = new GetSwitch();
   Switch profession = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.profswitch);
   profession.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new 
   CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
       @Override
       public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {      
           SP.setSetClicked(isChecked);
       } 
   }); 

   Button profButton = findViewById(R.id.btnSwitchNxt);
   profButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {      
           boolean setClicked = SP.isSetClicked();
           Log.i("GetSwitch",setClicked+"");
       }
   });
```